# Magento 2 how to encrypt customer phone number and email

Tags: magento2, customer

In Magento 2.3  i'am trying to encrypt customer phone number and email after registration.

Please help me out in this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> **Use This code to Encrypt & Decrypt**

```
$key = 'keydata'; //this is key 
$string = 'YourData';
```

> **To Encrypt:**

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(
    mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC),
    MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM
);

$encrypted = base64_encode(
    $iv .
    mcrypt_encrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        hash('sha256', $key, true),
        $string,
        MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
        $iv
    )
);
```

> **To Decrypt:**

```
$data = base64_decode($encrypted);
$iv = substr($data, 0, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));

$decrypted = rtrim(
    mcrypt_decrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        hash('sha256', $key, true),
        substr($data, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)),
        MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
        $iv
    ),
    "\0"
);
```

***I Hope This Helps***

Comment: Thanks a lot Msquare  for yout valuable comment ,  but actually i need for customer email and phone number when customer register these details need to encryption in database please help me out on this